# How to throw an exception in Asp.Net Core Web API action that returns Task<ActionResult>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How to throw exception in Asp.Net Core Web API action that returns Task?

When I try throw Exception, it gives following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Exception' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    string connectionString = "";
    string queueName = "";
    ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
    using ServiceBusMessageBatch batch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();

    ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("create order");

    if (!batch.TryAddMessage(message)) {
        // below gives compilation error
        return new Exception("unable to send message to azure service bus");
    }

    try
    {
        await sender.SendMessagesAsync(batch);
    }
    finally
    {
        await sender.DisposeAsync();
        await client.DisposeAsync();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't return an exception - you should log the error and return a 500 internal server error i.e. `return StatusCode(500);`

Comment: `return new Exception("unable to send message to azure service bus");` should be changed to `throw new Exception("unable to send message to azure service bus");`

Comment: ah my bad, it should be throw instead of return, thanks @ChetanRanpariya